# average 3d matrix matlab using reshape

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a 27x38x8760 matrix where the 27x38 represents a grid and the 8760 hours of the year. I would like to make daily avarages for the grid so that my resulting matrix is 27x38x365. 
I was using reshape for 2 dimensional matrix but is there a posibily to use it also for 3d?
kind regards Matthias

Comment: How wher you using reshape in order to  make daily averages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A` to be the input matrix, see if this works for you -

```
[m,n,r] = size(A)
daily_avg = squeeze(mean(reshape(A,m,n,24,[]),3))
```

Or avoid `squeeze` with `permute` -

```
daily_avg = mean(permute(reshape(A,m,n,24,[]),[1 2 4 3]),4)
```

Comment: Nice use of `reshape`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a loop,

```
A = rand([27 38 8760]);
for i = 1 : 24 :8760
    A_avg(:,:,ceil(i / 24)) = mean(A(:,:,i : i + 23),3);
end
```